# flutter dio error late LateInitializationError

Tags: android, flutter, api, dart, dio

First i got error 429 which means too many requests then i put in my Dio(BaseOptions)

- connectTimeout
- receiveTimeout
- sendTimeout

giving time trying to connect to the server. then i got the late Initialization error of DIO

## DIO CODE

```
class DioHelper {
  static late Dio dio;

  static init() {
    dio = Dio(
      BaseOptions(
        baseUrl: 'https://newsapi.org',
        receiveDataWhenStatusError: true,
        connectTimeout: dio.options.connectTimeout = 100000,
        receiveTimeout: dio.options.receiveTimeout = 30000,
        sendTimeout: dio.options.sendTimeout = 30000,
      ),
    );
  }

  static Future<Response> getData({
    required String url,
    required Map<String, dynamic> query,
  }) async {
    return await dio.get(
      url,
      queryParameters: query,
    );
  }
}
```

> ERROR: **Unhandled Exception: LateInitializationError: Field 'dio' has not been initialized.**

Comment: I'd say the issue is referring to `dio.options` when creating the `BaseOptions` instance - just use the values (`100000`, `30000` etc).

Comment: I think you should change `static late Dio dio;` to `static Dio? dio;`, I don't think you should static late values,  and add null checks, if you don't want to do null checks, you could make dio a getter and cache the value of init on a nullable variable

Comment: @msbit i tried that and it give me the " Http status error [429] " again

Comment: @h8moss seems my dio returning null so i can't do that :(

Comment: _i tried that and it give me the " Http status error [429] " again_ - not surprising considering you haven't addressed that issue. Normally, as part of the response, the API will indicate what kind of limits are in place, so take a look at both the body and the headers of the 429 response back from the API for more information. Also, consider removing your API key from your other question on this topic, as any request using that will come out of your quota.